# Как добавить в поле текст по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
  <input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text').value+='с'; 
  return false;" value = "с" />
  <input type = "text" name = "text" id="text" value = "" />
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку **с** в поле будет писаться буква **с**. Мне необходимо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку вставлялся html-код:

```
<option value="NAME">NAME</option>
```

Пробовал просто вставить в `value+='с';` вместо буквы **с** этот самый код, но ничего не работает, вообще всё слетает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй вот так:

> Код с одинарными кавычками:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text').value +='<option value=\'NAME\'>NAME</option>'; return false;" value = "с" />
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Код с двойными кавычками:

```
<input type="submit" onclick='document.getElementById("text").value +="<option value=\"NAME\">NAME</option>"; return false;' value = 'с'/>
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, но мне нужны не одинарные скобочки 'NAME', а двойные "NAME".