# Добавление в поле текста по нажатию кнопки, помогите!

Tags: html

Приветствую!

Имеется такой вот код:

```
<form action = "" method = "post">

<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('text').value+='с'; 
return false;"
value = "с" />

<input type = "text" name = "text" id="text" value = "" />

</form>
```

То есть при нажатии на кнопку **с** в поле будет писаться буква **с**. Мне необходимо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку вставлялся html-код:

```
<option value="NAME">NAME</option>
```

Пробовал просто вставить в **value+='с';** вместо буквы **с** этот самый код, но ничего не работает, вообще всё слетает.

Comment: Конечно слетает, "option" должен добавлятся к "select" a не текстовому полю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить в поле текст по нажатию кнопки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740787/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Вы в значение инпута хотите вставлять теги `html`? Вы в этом уверены? Может вам нужен "зависимые поля формы"? Нажали на кнопку - показались одни поля, не нажали - показываются другие поля.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="r();"></button>
<script>
function r(){
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.className = "NAME";
  option.innerHTML = "NAME";
  document.body.appendChild(option    );
}//вот , при нажатие кнопки вызывается функция r() которая вставляет тег option  с классом и контентом NAME в конец тега body
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем создавать form-submit, а потом отключать их функции? Можно тогда без этого всего) А то, что должно добавляться - записать в `data-` атрибуте, написав скрипт отдельно. Тогда если захочется добавить какую-то новую функцию, или поменять эту - не придется заново редактировать весь HTML.

```js
let tag = document.querySelectorAll('.tag');
let txt = document.getElementById('text');

for( let i = 0; i < tag.length; i++ ){
  tag[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    txt.value += this.dataset.add;
  });
}
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

#text {width: 500px;}
```

```html
<button class="tag" data-add='<option value="NAME">NAME</option>'>option</button>
<button class="tag" data-add='<b></b>'>b</button>
<button class="tag" data-add='<u></u>'>u</button>

<input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
```